# magento how to apply 2 coupon code at the same time

Tags: php, magento, coupon

I have two coupon codes that i am going to apply for single product but it is taking the only one coupons code discount. so please tell me how to apply 2 codes at the same time...

Answer (score 3):

This cannot be done out of the box. But there are extensions that allow you to add personalized coupon codes and add as many as you want in the cart.
[Here is an example](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/unirgy-giftcert.html). I'm in no way associated with the extension provider. I just used it in the past and was very happy with it.
I'm sure there are others.

Comment: thanks , your suggestion also good one